# Eclipse project does not display git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Here is the scenario:

I am building a new Joomla module that I want to add to the git repo at this location:

```
D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\Joomla\modules\mod_test
```

`mod_test` is also a git repo - it contains `.git` folder after running `git init`.

Now if I add a new PHP project in Eclipse located at this webserver location: `D:\Install\xampp\htdocs\Joomla`, the ENTIRE `modules` folder is not displayed in the `PHP Explorer` perspective.

However if I run the above steps the other way round (ie create the project in Eclipse first, then do `git init` inside `mod_test` folder), it keeps the `modules` folder visible. Has anyone experienced this before? Is this a normal Eclipse behaviour?

I intend to use git from the command line so that I don't have to add the entire `Joomla` folder as a local repo and I can add each extension as a separate repo as I go. Is this a right approach?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider creating the git repo at the root of the installation, and use a .gitignore to exclude core Joomla files: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Joomla.gitignore

Be careful as it may not be perfect, depending on your Joomla! version; I think this doesn't encompass 3.2 yet.  Always keep your eyes open when updating as you might be adding new core files as they are added; also keep separate backups in a safe place (not on the web host); in case things get messy you'll need them.

This will also prevent versioning any core hacks: one the more reason to avoid them.

Comment: Yes I initially wanted to create the git repo at the root of Joomla installation and use .gitignore file but I thought it was easier to create each extension as a separate repo so that they are more easily manageable. When I use .gitignore, I feel I regularly have to update this file every time I add new extensions. If I create separate repos within the Joomla installation folder, I can only focus on development. Is there a reason creating a single repo at root any better than creating separate repos?

Comment: Yes... think about setting up a development - test - production server array; think about moving servers; the fewer repos, the less administrative overhead and a single .git folder vs many. Also, with post-build hooks in eclipse you can set autocommit at once.  Of course, besides this, there are no major drawbacks to having them separate, it's not like it's going to break or malfunction if you keep them separate. Finally, when working on a package or component which has files in /media, it will still be in the same repo vs having 3 repos for one component (i.e. admin, frontend, media)